# "from gtts import gTTS" works fine in python 2.7 but it does not work in python 3.5. Why?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, import, gtts

I want to execute this code:

```
from gtts import gTTS
tts = gTTS('hello', lang='en')
tts.save('hello.mp3')
```

In python (python 2.7.13) works fine but in python3 (python 3.5.3) is not working.

It has always worked in the old python. Now, on a new PC (a raspberry) I wanted to start using the python3 (3.5.3) so I tried and it didn't work.

As it was a new installation, the gtts maybe was not installed, so I installed with:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ pip install gTTS
```

I had this:

```
Collecting gTTS
Downloading
...
...
...
Successfully built gTTS bs4 gtts-token
Installing collected packages: backports.functools-lru-cache, soupsieve, beautifulsoup4, bs4, click, idna, chardet, certifi, urllib3, requests, gtts-token, six, gTTS
Successfully installed backports.functools-lru-cache-1.5 beautifulsoup4-4.7.1 bs4-0.0.1 certifi-2019.3.9 chardet-3.0.4 click-7.0 gTTS-2.0.3 gtts-token-1.1.3 idna-2.8 requests-2.22.0 six-1.12.0 soupsieve-1.9.1 urllib3-1.25.2
pi@raspberrypi:/home $
```

I tried again and it was not working.
I tried with the old 2.7 version and for my surprise, it was working.

Working in python:

```
pi@raspberrypi:/ $ python
Python 2.7.13 (default, Sep 26 2018, 18:42:22) 
[GCC 6.3.0 20170516] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from gtts import gTTS
>>>
```

Not working in python3

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ python3
Python 3.5.3 (default, Sep 27 2018, 17:25:39) 
[GCC 6.3.0 20170516] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from gtts import gTTS
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'gtts'
>>>
```

Then, I noticed that there is pip3 !
When I do

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo pip3 install gTTS
```

gTTS is not there, so I did

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo pip3 install gTTS
```

But after doing that i get red text and error msg

```
 File "/usr/share/python-wheels/urllib3-1.19.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 643, in urlopen
    _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/urllib3-1.19.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 315, in increment
    total -= 1
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -=: 'Retry' and 'int'
```

When I check again with pip list, gTTS is still not there...
Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are complaining that you ran a certain intpreter and saw:

```
from gtts import gTTS
...
ImportError: No module named 'gtts'
```

or more succinctly:

```
import gtts
...
ImportError: No module named 'gtts'
```

The difficulty is that you never installed gtts for that interpreter.

Yes, you ran `pip` (or equivalently, `pip2`),
which offers terrific service for your python2.7 interpreter.
No, you never ran `pip3`,
which might work well for your python3.5 interpreter.

It would probably be better to invoke it in this way:

```
$ python3 -m pip install gTTS
```

Then you're quite sure what `sys.path` will be during installation,
and that the package will land in the right place
for `import` to find it.

As a separate item, 3.5 is a bit old,
consider using a newer version.

Comment: Thanks a lot !!! Indeed, I tried with "$ python3 -m pip install gTTS" and then indeed, I could do the import! Awesome... !!!

Comment: Why is this a thing? I have installed Python with version 3.9 for the first time in my life and had the same issue. Why would it use some outdated version of pip as a default?